# How do you perform deep array updates with mobx?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have one observable array in my store that is deeply nested. Lets called the property people (which contains elements of class Person). Now the Person class has a property products which is an array of Product, a class which also has nesting through ShippingInformation and so on. When the app is loaded I get the people array with all nested data. Now upon any data update I receive the updated peoples array again from the server. A lot of the times the elements in the people array are the same, the only change being some ShippingInformation.

Now how should I update the existing observable array people? I do not want to reassign it because often times the direct Person elements are the same. It is only some nested information on one Person that has changed. Is there a way that I can sync the two arrays without changing the ref on the array with a reassign so that I avoid major rerenders in react? Can mobx help me here or are there any other lib I can use to help me update without triggering unnecessary rerenders? If not, are these rerenders that bad, performance wise, I guess react must go through the diffing process at least

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code on codeSandBox or similar

Comment: Why don't you just update the relevant properties based on your conditions on what have changed?